# Google Chrome microphone change drop-down

Tags: google-chrome, microphone

Earlier Google Chrome was able to change microphone or webcam from ask-permission popup, after last updates that drop-down blocked, I can click it and it animate click but don't "opens". I searched for `chrome://flags` but haven't found setting for it.

Is is possible to unlock that drop-down? [Here's Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJjwk.png)

Comment: I downloaded & installed the Chrome voice dication add-on this afternoon and it works fine, fwiw.

Comment: Maybe its caused by windows 10's bug?